# Hash from different files is always the same

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm building an API which has a method that accepts a file via POST request.
Based on that file, i need to create a hash on the file itself (not the name), check if the hash already exists and do some other actions.

My problem is that whatever file i will send through postman, the hash is always the same for every file, which means that every time i get only 1 file which is overwritten.

Here is my method

```
 private string GetHashFromImage(IFormFile file)
    {
        /* Creates a hash with the image as a parameter
         * with the SHA1 algorithm and returns the hash
         * as a string since the ComputeHash() method 
         * creates a byte array.
         */
         System.IO.MemoryStream image = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
         file.CopyTo(image);
         var hashedValue = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(image);
         var hashAsString = Convert.ToBase64String(hashedValue).Replace(@"/", @"");
         image.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

         return hashAsString;
        }
    }
```

I need a hash method that is agnostic to OS and will return the same hash on each file.

Comment: It looks like you need to rewind the MemoryStream.

Comment: Tried to do image.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin); but didn't work
image.Position = 0; didn't work either

Comment: What is the value of `file`? Does the `file.Length` field show that there are indeed some bytes? What is the content of `MemoryStream` before and after your `CopyTo()` call? These are basic debug checks, you have to do them. And what is the current full source code you have?

Comment: The file indeed exists since  after creating the hash i create a method that copies it's content to a directory (well that's how i save it) so the bytes are there.  Trying 2 different files returns different length.  One returns 31466 bytes and the other one 199744

Comment: Edit your question to include the new current full source code you have. Also save the return value of `ComputeHash()` in a variable and output the content before put it into `Convert.ToBase64String()`

Comment: did you try to hash on array of bytes: var fileBytes = image.ToArray(); ...ComputeHash(fileBytes); probably there is a need to Flush the data after CopyTo

Comment: Progman I edited the code, also the value still remains the same.
Ivan, the file is a IFormFile which doesn't have a .ToArray() method since it's already in bytes.

Comment: @Woops You have to rewind AFTER you have copied the bytes but BEFORE you compute the hash. It doesn't make sense to rewind the `MemoryStream` when you already have calculated the hash.

Comment: @Woops Why do you use `CopyTo` and an additional `MemoryStream` anyway? Wouldn't it be easier to use `OpenReadStream()`?

Comment: @Progman, well here we are moving .seek() before hashedValue does the job and works.
Also i do it that way since my BG is mostly Python and those are the first steps into adapting C# and the answers i found while searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely sure why you're solution is not working but I think I have an idea on how to achieve what you want and it uses `MD5` instead of SHA1.

Let's create a function that will receive an `IFormFile`, compute the MD5 hash of its contents then return the hash value as a `string`.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

private string GetMD5Hash(IFormFile file)
{
    // get stream from file then convert it to a MemoryStream
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    file.OpenReadStream().CopyTo(stream);
    // compute md5 hash of the file's byte array.
    byte[] bytes = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(stream.ToArray());
    return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-",string.Empty).ToLower();
}
```

Hope it works for you!

Comment: Well. wow.  This worked!
Thanks. 
I have  to adapt the philosophy of C# since i mostly use Python.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The real reason of this behaviour is the **last position** (same as position after `image.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.End)`) in the calculated stream.

Stream operations like `CopyTo`, `ComputeHash`, etc change the position of sreams because they have to iterate through them. **The final hash of any stream with position on the end is always same - like a hash of empty stream or empty array.**

Convert stream to array works, of course, because to array function works with whole stream (from position = 0) but it is not generally very elegant solution because you have to copy whole stream into memory (this is same for memory stream - the data are also in memory).

When you work directly with stream the function (like compute hash from stream) reads the stream by small chunks (like 4096B) and compute hash iteretively ([.NET source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/hashalgorithm.cs,57)). It means that original solution should work when the seek operation to the start is performed before hash calculation.

Actually you should be able to compute hash directly from input stream (in `IFormFile`) without copy whole stream into memory (array or memory stream) with better performance and without risk e.g. `OutOfMemoryException`.